# how to create bookmarks within table

Tags: ms-word, bookmarks

I am automating the word document processing where I add bookmarks based on a search criteria. The code works great but it fails when I have tables in the document. It seems like in the normal document when I read the text it is given as line per line but in case of tables the text has columns and rows. So, when I seach a text and that text is written in two lines in a single column the result would be ok but when I select the text WORD API selects the text from two columns instead of the same column but two lines.

```
col1          col2
This is       Second Column
Some Text
```

Now if I search the text "This is Some text" I got it correctly but when I select it I got "This is Second Column"

```
reg = New Regex(result.token(j).ToString())
                Dim m As Match = reg.Match(_doc.Range.Text, 0)
                pos = m.Index ' start position is fine

                ''  start is the starting position of the token in the content...
                ''length is the size of the token
                len = result.token(j).ToString().Length ' text length is fine

                rng = _doc.Range(pos, len + pos) ' this copies the text from the second col
                _doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, rng)
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question: `Now if I search the text "This is Some text" I got it correctly` works well, so what's wrong? Are `This is` and `Some Text` in two different rows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, in order to add a bookmark, I first search for the text by using regular expression and it tells me that the string exist and the starting position of the text. Then I select the text as _doc.Range(pos, lenofString + pos) this should select the actual text right? So in my example, if the text that I am looking for is "This is some text" then this code should select it but what happens is that it selects "This is Second column" which means it does not know if the text is written inside a cell and it just read it as rows. Does it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of selecting the text by length, you can select the whole cell, try to adapt your code this way:

```
rng = Selection.Cells(1).Range
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case the document does not contain just tables. The text that I want to search may be written inside a table cell or just outside any table (as a flat text). How do I know if the text that I found is written inside a table cell. If there is no table then the code works great but if there is a table which also contains the keywords then it does not work correctly.

Comment: ok i understand. So, you can try: `If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then` but i can't test it right here, it *should* work

Comment: Thanks JMax for helping me. I have changed the way I was approaching this problem. I am now using the Find method of Word to extract the information and then convert it to bookmark. The problem with my approach was that when I read the document it contains not only the text but some extra meta characters or symbols that was corrupting my search.

Comment: i'm glad you found a new way to handle your issue. if you still have problems, you'd better create a new question so that other users will feel concerned and give you some tips and answers